# How to spot unused files

Tags: php, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a big system with 100 + files in php, we want to clean it up a bit by removing unused files.

My idea was to create logs in each file, if the file is executed then send it's directory to cloudwatch, but that seems to overload cloudwatch and it will be expensive too as the same file is called several times inside loops etc.

What are the options available to do such thing?

Comment: Define "unused"

Comment: A file in the system that is no longer executed by any means. Decisions was made to not use it either because it was deprecated/unwanted/forgotten/bugged.